# MySQL Join 3 Tables on Single Resource ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have three tables

- `resources_connection`

  1. resource_id
  2. resource_tag_id
- `resources_flags`

  1. user_id
  2. resource_id
- `resources_votes`

  1. user_id
  2. resource_id

Each is a 2 column table, int (11) for both designed to allow me to query the number of tags, flags and votes based on a single 'resource id'

I am currently using this query to try and get a count of tags (`resources_connection`), flags(`resources_flags`) and votes(`resources_votes`):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.resource_id) as votes,
        COUNT(DISTINCT t2.resource_id) as flags,
        COUNT(DISTINCT t3.resource_tag_id) as tags
FROM ecruit_demo.resources_votes t1
LEFT JOIN ecruit_demo.resources_flags t2
    ON (t1.resource_id = t2.resource_id)
JOIN ecruit_demo.resources_connection t3
    ON (t1.resource_id = t3.resource_id) WHERE t1.resource_id = 4
```

The problem is that this query returns proper results for `resource_id = 1` but when I set `resource_id` to **4** (for which there is a tag) it returns all zeros. What would be the proper query structure to ensure that this query always returns the proper count of tags, flags and votes for a given `resource_id`?

I should also add that the only place resource_id = 4 occurs in the database is in resources_connection, the other two tables do not have this value

Comment: Thanks @Back in a Flash for editing the format of the query to make it readable

Comment: which of the following is the main table?

Comment: There isn't really a main table. These tables are meant to hold values related to a 'Resource' object which is comprised of an id, name, description and url. For the purposes of this question there will be many votes, flags and tags for each resource object coming from many users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  resource_ID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN types = 'votes' THEN totals ELSE NULL END) votes,
        MAX(CASE WHEN types = 'flags' THEN totals ELSE NULL END) flags,
        MAX(CASE WHEN types = 'tags' THEN totals ELSE NULL END) tags
FROM    
    (
        SELECT  resource_ID, 'votes' types, 
                COUNT(DISTINCT resource_ID) totals
        FROM    resources_votes
        GROUP   BY resource_ID
        UNION
        SELECT  resource_ID, 'flags' types, 
                COUNT(DISTINCT resource_ID) totals
        FROM    resources_flags
        GROUP   BY resource_ID
        UNION
        SELECT  resource_ID, 'tags' types, 
                COUNT(DISTINCT resource_tag_id) totals
        FROM    resources_connection
        GROUP   BY resource_ID
    ) s
-- WHERE    resource_ID = 1
GROUP   BY resource_ID
```

Comment: Returns `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: do you have `s` after the subquery?

Comment: For some reason, I thought that that was a typo. This works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really good in mysql but maybe you can try:

change JOIN to LEFT JOIN so the query would be like this.

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.resource_id) as votes,
            COUNT(DISTINCT t2.resource_id) as flags,
            COUNT(DISTINCT t3.resource_tag_id) as tags
    FROM ecruit_demo.resources_votes t1
    LEFT JOIN ecruit_demo.resources_flags t2
        ON (t1.resource_id = t2.resource_id)
    LEFT JOIN ecruit_demo.resources_connection t3
        ON (t1.resource_id = t3.resource_id) WHERE t1.resource_id = 4
```

Comment: Returns all zeros same as the original query :-(